# Kubernetes go client: list events

Tags: go, kubernetes

I am trying to get a list of events in the namespace, but with or without FieldSelector I get an empty list. Is this the right way to do it?

```
            eventListOptions := metav1.ListOptions{FieldSelector: fields.OneTermEqualSelector("involvedObject.name", job.Name).String()}
            jobEvents, _ := clientset.EventsV1beta1().Events(GetNamespace()).List(eventListOptions)
```

Comment: Hi, have you tried to get the error? `jobEvents, myWonderfulError :`

Comment: no, this is not the right way. You silence the error. `jobEvents, _ := clientset.Evente...` -> `jobEvents, err := clientset.Event... \n if err != nil{//handle}`

Answer (score 1):

If you print error return by `List`, you should get error something like `"involvedObject.name" is not a known field selector: only "metadata.name", "metadata.namespace"`

use `CoreV1` instead of `EventsV1beta1`

The line will be something like below:

`jobEvents, _ := clientset.CoreV1().Events(GetNamespace()).List(eventListOptions)`

---

`"involvedObject.name", job.Name` isn't supported by `EventsV1beta1`

Hope it'll help.

Comment: any particular reason for down vote? It will help to improve answer.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer that did the trick for me, moving to corev1

`events, err := clientset.CoreV1().Events(namespace).List(metav1.ListOptions{
      FieldSelector: fmt.Sprintf("involvedObject.name=%s,involvedObject.namespace=%s", item.Name, item.Namespace),
   })`